# Nuxt Auth + socialite manual login

Tags: laravel, oauth, authorization, nuxt.js, laravel-socialite

I am trying to use the Nuxt Auth module and socialite for social logins. I have an API in Laravel 8 and a client in NuxtJS.

I am wondering if someone could tell me:

- If my logic here is ok?
- How to manually log user with nuxt auth (manually set token and user)?

So currently here is my flow for social logins:

1. Click on `login with google` makes an API call to my backend where I get redirect URL from socialite to google.
2. My frontend redirects me to the google login page, then back to my frontend app after I picked the account.
3. I send the google code to the backend to callback endpoint for socialite which then grabs me the google user. In same place after I deal with users in my app I am returning the token which I create by doing `return $this->okResponse(['token' => $nativeUser->createToken('social-login')->accessToken]);`
4. At this point I am back in my front end with the token which then I am trying to set `this.$auth.setUserToken(response.data.token)` which apparently does not equal logging the user in. So it looks like this:

```js
mounted() {
    this.$axios.get(`login/social/google/callback`, {params: {code: this.$route.query.code}}).then(response => {
      console.log(response)

      // this.$auth.strategy.token.set(response.data.token)
      this.$auth.setUserToken(response.data.token)

      if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
        console.log('I am logged in!')
      } else {
        console.log('I am NOT logged in!', this.$auth)
      }
    })
  }
```

I am not logged in. Do I have to manually set `loggedIn`, 'User' and `token`? Or this is just madness? The only other thing I see here as a solution is my own custom strategy but this seems like total overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best way but I ended up doing something like this.

```js
  mounted() {
    this.$axios.get(`login/social/google/callback`, {params: {code: this.$route.query.code}}).then(response => {
      this.$auth.setUserToken(response.data.token)
      this.$auth.setUser(response.data.user)

      if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
        console.log('I am logged in!')
      } else {
        console.log('I am NOT logged in!', this.$auth)
      }
    })
  }
```

This seems to be working ok.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't relate much with the answer, but I'm stuck with CORS redirect issue with LAMP. could you spare me some approaches you did to overcome CORS issue? I'm stuck with getting 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nerdar do you use Laravel for API? If you do Laravel will handle that for you unless you left dd() somewhere, it will stop middleware from running. I am using Docker. Depending on what you are doing for the backend you might need to look into documentation of that tool.